# How does two dimensional induction work for my special case?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, proof-writing, induction, education

In one dimensional induction we show something holds for $n=0$ or $n=1$ and assume it is true at $n=n$ and prove for $n=n+1$.

In two dimensional induction is it something along show it is true for $(n,k)=(0,k)$ or $(n,k)=(1,k)$ at any $k$ and assume it is true at $(n,k)=(n,k)$ and prove for $(n,k)=(n+1,k)$?

In my case $n\leq k$ always.

Comment: What you've written out in your second paragraph isn't double induction, it's regular induction on $n$ with an irrelevant letter $k$ being used as a decoration.

Comment: @JackM That's technically true, but I think it's pedagogically irrelevant. In my experience, if there are two variables floating around, and you need to induct, then you'll get confused if you don't understand double induction - even if what you end up doing isn't technically double induction after all.

Comment: I would recommend against writing "nonsense" equations like "$n = n + 1$". You should work out what you actually mean by such statements and choose notation and terminology accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Proving that the $(0,k)$ case holds for all $k$, and that $(n,k) \implies (n+1,k)$ for all $k$, is one valid way to do two-dimensional induction. (In fact, you could also think of it as a one-dimensional induction on $n$, leaving $k$ as an arbitrary fixed constant.)

There are other ways to do it. Another common setup for two-dimensional induction is proving that $(0,0)$ holds, that $(n,k) \implies (n+1,k)$, and that $(n,k) \implies (n,k+1)$.

It's better not to focus on specifics, and think about what actually makes the induction work. The key thing to check is: for any case $(n,k)$, is there a path of implications you've proven that starts at a base case, and ends at $(n,k)$?

This is true in the case in your question: we have the path
$$(0,k) \implies (1,k) \implies \dots \implies (n-1,k) \implies (n,k).$$
This is true in the other example I gave: we have the path
$$(0,0) \implies (0,1) \implies \dots \implies (0,k) \implies (1,k) \implies \dots \implies (n,k).$$

There are always going to be examples which mess with the template, but work because such a path always exists. The weirdest example I know of is one-dimensional - a proof of the fundamental theorem of algebra by Laplace, which takes all odd $n$ as a base case, and proves the implication $\binom{n}{2} \implies n$. This really seems like it ought not to work, but you can show that for every $n$, there's a path that starts at an odd number and uses this implication to get to $n$. (For example, to get to $4$, you take the path $45 \implies 10 \implies 4$.)

That's a digression, but the point is that you shouldn't try to memorize templates for induction that work. Instead, check if every case has a proof - a chain of implications that lead to that case from a base case.

Comment: In my case $k\geq n$ always.

Comment: In that case, the $(n,k) \implies (n+1,k)$ induction step might not work well: certainly the implication $(k,k) \implies (k+1,k)$ shouldn't work. But you could go the other way: start with the base cases $(n,n)$ for all $n$, and prove that $(n,k) \implies (n,k+1)$.

Comment: that I think helps. I have $k \times k$  matrices of rank $n$ that I want to prove something. So prove $n=1$ and $k=1$ and assume for $k=n$ and prove for $k>n$. However that only proves for rank up to $n$ not beyond it. is there a better technique?

Comment: If you're set on using induction, you usually start with figuring out what induction steps you *can* show, and then you see what that gives you and what base cases you need. You might want to ask a more specific question about your problem.